# The enemy does not pursue when the player is behind the obstacle

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I use some ways and it does not work. How can I make this enemy attack player if player in enemy range. And the enemy will stop attacking the player if player behind the obstacle

```
var playertarget : Transform; //the enemy's target
var bigboss : Transform; //current transform data of this enemy

var rotationSpeed = 3; //speed of turning
//SPEED LEVEL MOVE
var slv1 = 5;
var slv2 = 3;
var slv3 = 1;
var speedrandommove = 1;

function Awake() {
    bigboss = transform; //cache transform data for easy access/preformance
}

function Start() {
     playertarget = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform; //target the player
}

function Update() {
    var distance = parseInt((playertarget.position - bigboss.position).magnitude);

    //RANGE
    if (distance < 5) {
        boss_move_to_player('2');
    } else if (distance < 10) {
        boss_move_to_player('2');
    } else if (distance < 20) {
        boss_move_to_player('3');
    } else {
        boss_move_random();
    }
}

function boss_move_to_player(speedtime) {
    //rotate to look at the player
    if(speedtime == "1") {
        speedtime = slv1;
    } else if(speedtime == "2") {
        speedtime = slv2;
    } else {
        speedtime = slv3;
    }
    bigboss.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(bigboss.rotation,
    Quaternion.LookRotation(playertarget.position - bigboss.position), rotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);

    //move towards the player
    bigboss.position += bigboss.forward * speedtime * Time.deltaTime;
}

function boss_move_random() {
    bigboss.Translate(Vector3(0, 0, 2) * speedrandommove * Time.deltaTime);
    var randomint = Random.Range(0,360);
    var fwd = bigboss.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    var hit:RaycastHit;
    Debug.DrawRay(bigboss.position, fwd*3, Color.red);
    if(Physics.Raycast(bigboss.position, fwd, hit, 3)) {
        print(hit.collider.tag);
        if(hit.collider.tag=="Penghalang") {
            bigboss.Rotate(0,randomint,0);
        }
    }
}
```

how can i do that?

I use the code "boss_move_random()" to make a enemy run randomly, if player is not in the enemy range

and I use the function "boss_move_to_player(speedtime)", if player goes into enemy range

Comment: In boss_move_to_player, you have to check if an obstacle is present between your boss and your player, that is raycast from your boss to your player and check if the tag is different than "Player".  In this case, you have to compute another pathway from your boss to your player.

Comment: the enemy is not looking for another way if the player is behind the obstacle